# reverting commits from pending pull request

Tags: git

I have a pending PR which adds a specific feature and by mistake, I pushed some other features in that branch and pushed which make both features to be merged in my pending pull request
this pull request is old and I had a lot of code merged after that PR which I don't want to be removed, I just need the code which I pushed by mistake to be removed from my pull request
I tried to search stack overflow but there are a lot of different ways which I am not able to understand which one is safe for me

Answer (score 1):

Use

> git revert commit-hash

This will create a new commit reverting the changes of the specified commit. This can be pushed into the pull request  branch.

The commit hash of the commit can be obtained  by

> git log

in the specified branch

Comment: wont git revert commit-hash revert all the commits after commit-hash ?